# DeleteAsync doesn't work with 2 post request

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, post, http-post

I have an async method to delete a date on my Firebase DB. This works fine when I send one post request but when I send 2 request at the same time, sometimes the method DeleteAsync() doesn't work and I don't know why. I'm not seeing any problem.

```
public async Task DeleteCardFromFirebaseAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(url);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what exception are you getting? You should probably log it instead of catching and then immediately rethrowing it. That's kind of pointless.

Comment: It does not return an exception. When I debugged, I could see the way:
public async method... -> try block -> client.DeleteAsync () -> end method

Comment: What's the status code in `response`?

Comment: Remove the try, catch block, to be able to see what is happening.

Comment: @glenebob the status code is 200. Doesn't work yet, but look this status help me to fix another error. Thanks

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Nothing happened. But I changed the logic. Thanks

Comment: Sure nothing will happen when you remove the try catch, just we needed more info, `does not work` is not an error message